# In UX, which is the main branch for health disciplines?

Tags: taxonomy, health, definition

We're rebuilding our main website and giving more importance to the projects we worked on. Since we're working a lot with health related projects (mainly psychology and neurology), I'm building a taxonomy tree diagram using UX disciplines.
[image]

But I'm not sure where to place these health related projects. The closest would be interaction design, but some of those projects are for physical UX and IoT, so they could easily go under Ergonomics or Universal UX. Thus, it's too ambiguous and broad.

Example: we need to add a project for an app that works in its owmn device and uses AI to identify problems in people with Alzheimer. And another that uses only physical objects for autistic people. And another for digital experiences for autistic people. And another that attends people with anxiety.

I understand I could add them to the specific type of user interaction (HCI, physical, IoT, whatever). But on the one hand, I really want this specialization in neuropsychology to be a *"selling point."* And on the other hand, the level of knowledge they require **dives deep into the neuropsychological sciences**, far more than just *"coding an app."*

So the question is: **is there a proper UX taxonomy that specifically contains health related projects?** And if so, is there some kind of **child taxonomies** that divide those projects into **medical specialties**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why not give them two lenses in which to view your offerings?**

It seems like your map above is taking overlapping and adjacent capabilities, but in the world of finished projects, these bounds tend to either lose meaning, or have non-adjacent connections.

#### Think of how the business buyers view the world.

In the business world, healthcare is widely seen as a sector (or vertical), not a capability, skillset, subset or facet embedded in a taxonomy of skills/disciples/capabilities used to solve the problem itself.

For, instance a hospital might need 1 or  more of  the **outputs** you have in yellow, but those don't classify as 'healthcare' but a possible universe of artifacts (or techniques such as scenario design) to solve our healthcare problem, using:

- user interface design
- guidance systems
- interactive environments

Also, non-ux people (often the buyers) rarely understand all the terms in the taxonomy. They also often don't even know the real problem they have, and could be totally surprised at parts of the taxonomy that applies to the solution. (i.e. they think they need an iPhone app, but they really need a wearable solution, or just a better notification system).

Even being in house in a tech company, we constantly need to communicate how these facets can work together towards software experiences.

They may think more concretely in terms of 'have these folks tackled problems in healthcare? I hope so...'

**Clients can view / toggle by capabilities or by sectors**

If you're trying to give potential clients a sense of 'we can do this', can you build some kind of way to view in terms of sectors (healthcare, aviation, transit, editorial), with that taxonomy viewing as tags? That way you have all kinds of projects that could involve IoT, AI, usability engineering, media installations, etc.

Hope i understood the problem; I'll update if it can be clearer / useful.

Comment: The "tags" idea was what I was completely missing, thenk you Mike! :)

Answer (score 2):

The Ergonomics people have always had a health subdivision:

https://www.ergonomics.org.uk/Public/Resources/Sectors/Healthcare.aspx

Comment: Yes Philip, I was aware of that, but they don't have a taxonomy, they just mention it as a field in which EHF works (which is why I also mentioned it as one of the possibilities). But you will see that it focuses only on the medical sciences, leaving everything else aside (which is quite logical since it is 'ergonomics'). However, it is a very good link and read by everyone, I loved it and I learned some new and very useful things for future projects! 

Side note: it's amazing to see the level of "deep UX" in Europe and specially in UK and Germany

Answer (score 1):

On the healthcare and medical device side, you often run in to regulations related to product design.  In these regulated environments, the regulations are Human Factors regulations.  For that reason, I would suggest more towards the Human Factors and Ergonomics area.